# FAB button on card spanning content sections with MDL

Tags: material-design-lite

How do I get my FAB to appear on a card like the example below?

[image]
My card is set up as follows

[image]

What I really want is the Orange FAB to straddle the Blue and White line. How do I go about this with Material design lite?

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS for the card that holds the FAB, put:

```
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
```

In the CSS for the FAB (assuming it belongs to the above view), put:

```
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
bottom: -25px;
```

If the FAB is in the below view, change

```
bottom: -25px;
```

to

```
top: -25px;
```

You might have to make some small adjustments for responsiveness (I'm pretty green at web development), but that'll get you started.